# How to detect and extract date data formats from a OCR generated text files in python

Tags: python, image, tesseract

I am creating a date extractor from images using python.

After reading the images and converting it to **.txt** files, I am having a list of text files containing dates in it which are in different formats.

**like**

20-april-2019

20-04-2019

20-4-19

apr-20-2019

Apr-20-19

20Apr-2019

and so on

I want to identify and extract date data from the above text.
Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) module

```
import dateparser
print(dateparser.parse('20Apr-2019'))
```

Gives:

```
2019-04-20 00:00:00
```

[dateparser.parse](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#dateparser.parse) returns a datetime object.

If your text file contains other strings, and the task is to identify the dates as well as extracting them, you can use [dateparser.search](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#dateparser.search.search_dates).

```
from dateparser.search import search_dates
str1 = "Whurat UDAYA FILLING STATION MATTUPATTY ROAD MUNNAR 04865230318 ORIGINAL De DD De Da ED eH DAC Da a Da Oa DC Oa DO Dt Oe 29-MAY -2019 14:02:23 INVOICE NO: 292 i VEHICLE NO: NOT ENTERED (| NOZZLE NO : 1 f PRODUCT: PETROL RATE : 75.01 INR/Ltr VOLUME: 1.33 Ltr AMOUNT: 100.00 INR ek DA DH DE DC DE DRC DC DDC cok DE DC CDC DC DE DE S.T..No : 27430268741C M.S.T. No: 27430268741V pe TE ETA CT a DD OC DRE I BOC IE DOC Thank You! Visit Again"
print(search_dates(str1))
```

Which gives:

```
[('04865230318', datetime.datetime(1985, 6, 2, 2, 17, 11)), ('29-MAY -2019 14:02:23', datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 29, 14, 2, 23)), ('292', datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 2, 9, 2)), ('100', datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 1, 0)), ('ek', datetime.datetime(1900, 10, 1, 0, 0)), ('TE', datetime.datetime(1900, 7, 1, 0, 0)), ('OC', datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0))]
```

As you can see, this may need some further filtering to eliminate false positives, but it should catch most of the dates you throw at it.